# how to add apache httpclient .zip library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to add Apache HTTP client to my project but how should i do that?

there is just some .zip files [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

i couldn't find any .jar file to add my project even after extracting .zip file and adding .zip files doesn't work.
[here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

Comment: download zip file and unzip it. you will find jars inside

Comment: What ZIP file do you have exactly? I just downloaded the last binary `httpcomponents-client-4.5.2-bin.zip` which contains a lot of JAR files under `lib` directory. At the download page you should choose a binary distribution instead of source.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is using MAVEN, create maven project and download apache httpclient from maven repository.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39279/create-a-new-maven-project-in-eclipse/

and after that write dependency in dependencies section

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Using the _maven_ build infrastructure is a very good advice. Though no longer downloading jars yourself, and java sources under `src/main/java` and resource files under `src/main/resources`.